# Neo4j / Cypher query syntax feedback

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm developing a kind of reddit service to learn Neo4j. 
Everything works fine, I just want to get some feedback on the Cypher query to get the most recent news stories, the author and number of comments, likes and dislikes.

I'm using Neo4j 2.0.

```
MATCH comments = (n:news)-[:COMMENT]-(o)
MATCH likes = (n:news)-[:LIKES]-(p)
MATCH dislikes = (n:news)-[:DISLIKES]-(q)
MATCH (n:news)-[:POSTED_BY]-(r)
WITH n, r, count(comments) AS num_comments, count(likes) AS num_likes, count(dislikes) AS num_dislikes
ORDER BY n.post_date
LIMIT 20
RETURN *
```

`o`, `p`, `q`, `r` are all nodes with the label `user`. Should the label be added to the query to speed it up?

Is there anything else you see that I could optimize?

Comment: What about posts that have neither likes nor dislikes or comments? They would not show up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to want to get rid of the multiple matches. Cypher will filter on each one, filtering through one another, rather than getting all the information.

I would also avoid the paths like comments, and rather do the count on the nodes you are saving. When you do MATCH xyz = (a)-[:COMMENT]-(b) then xyz is a path, which contains the source, relationship and destination node.

```
MATCH (news:news)-[:COMMENT]-(comment),(news:news)-[:LIKES]-(like),(news:news)-[:DISLIKES]-(dislike),(news:news)-[:POSTED_BY]-(posted_by) 
WHERE news.post_date > 0 
WITH news, posted_by, count(comment) AS num_comments, count(like) AS num_likes, count(dislike) AS num_dislikes 
ORDER BY news.post_date 
LIMIT 20 
RETURN *
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I did not know there were any difference in writing `,` instead of a new `MATCH` statement.

I need to see who has liked/disliked a news story, but I guess the solution is to both save the number of likes/dislikes on the news node as well as making relationships.

Comment: Nicolas, can you contact me at michael at neotechnology dot com?

Comment: +1 on the aggregation of information on the post in case this becomes a bottleneck

Comment: I wasn't aware either, until I ran the query in http://www.neo4j.org/console and asked it to explain the execution plan. It shows that it was using a multi-level filter, which I believe is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
MATCH (n:news)-[:POSTED_BY]->(r)
WHERE n.post_date > {recent_start_time}
RETURN n, r, 
        length((n)<-[:COMMENT]-()) AS num_comments,
        length((n)<-[:LIKES]-()) AS num_likes,
        length((n)<-[:DISLIKES]-()) AS num_dislikes,
ORDER BY n.post_date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

To speed it up and have not neo search over all your posts, I would probably index the post-date field (assuming it doesn't contain time information). And then send this query in for today, yesterday etc. until you have your 20 posts.

```
MATCH (n:news {post_date: {day}})-[:POSTED_BY]->(r)
RETURN n, r, 
        length((n)<-[:COMMENT]-()) AS num_comments,
        length((n)<-[:LIKES]-()) AS num_likes,
        length((n)<-[:DISLIKES]-()) AS num_dislikes,
ORDER BY n.post_date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thanks! This will show news that has no comments or likes as well? When you say "assuming it doesn't contain time information", what do you mean? `post_date` is a unix timestamp.

I see that I should have removed `WHERE n.post_date > 0` from  my question, it should always be > 0.